# How to summarize pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing ~20,xxx records of bus boarding data. The dataset contains a `cardNumber` field which is unique for each passenger. There is a `type` field that identifies the type of boarding. There is a `routeName` column specifying which route the boarding took place on and finally a `Date` column which identifies when the boarding took place. I have provided a mock dataframe below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cardNumber': ['999', '999', '999', '999', '901', '901', '888', '888'],
     'type': ['trip_pass', 'transfer', 'trip_pass', 'transfer', 'stored_value', 'transfer', 'trip_pass', 
              'trip_pass'],
     'routeName': ['1', '2', '2', '1', '20', '3', '4', '4'],
     'Date': ['2020-08-01 06:18:56 -04:00', '2020-08-01 06:46:12 -04:00', '2020-08-01 17:13:51 -04:00',
              '2020-08-01 17:47:32 -04:00', '2020-08-10 15:23:16 -04:00', '2020-08-10 15:44:45 -04:00',
              '2020-08-31 06:54:09 -04:00', '2020-08-31 16:23:41 -04:00']}
)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

What I would like to do is summarize the transfer activity. How many transfers, on average, occurred from Route 1 to Route 2 or from Route 2 to Route 1. There are eleven different routes in the dataset that transfers could happen between.

I would like the output to look something like (note that the output below was not generated from the sample provided above):

```
From   |   To     |   Avg. Daily
----------------------------------
 1     |   2      |     45.7
 1     |   3      |     22.6
 20    |   1      |     12.2
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the above data?

Comment: How do you know which route went to another? I think your data (at least the chunk you provided) doesn't have such information.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva, that's one of the issues I think I'm running into. I'm thinking those relationships have to be forced. For example, the cardNumber 999, you can see that the passenger boarded Route 1 and then transferred to Route 2. I didn't know if there was a way to group by `cardNumber` and then sort by `Date`. Then pull the record directly before the transfer record to identify the transfer.

Comment: @QuangHoang I edited the post to show the desired output.

Comment: Which column does `Avg. Daily` come from? How do you define a *transfer from Route 2 to Route 1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `Avg. Daily` would have to be created once you were able to summarize the data. As for defining a transfer, see the comment to CainaMaxCouto-Silva. I'm thinking those transfers are going to have to be defined manually, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in the chunk data you provided. If it doesn't work in your actual data, pls let me know. There's probably better ways to do that, but I think it's a good starting point.

The general idea here is to group by passengers to figure out the route. Then, since you want the daily average, you gonna need to group by date, and then by destinations in order to calculate the daily mean.

```
# Define a function to get routes' relationship (origin vs destination)
def get_routes(x):
    if 'transfer' not in x.type.tolist(): # if no 'transfer' type in group, leave it as 0 (we'll remove them afterwards)
        return 0
    x = x[x.type == 'transfer'] # select target type
    date = df[df.cardNumber=='999'].Date.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').unique()
    if date.size == 1: # if there is more than one date by passenger, you'll need to change this code
        date = date[0]
    else:
        raise Exception("There are more than one date per passenger, please adapt your code.")
    s_from = x.routeName[x.Date.idxmin()] # get route from the first date
    s_to = x.routeName[x.Date.idxmax()] # get route from the last date
    return date, s_from, s_to

# Define a function to get the routes' daily average
def get_daily_avg(date_group):
    daily_avg = (
        date_group.groupby(['From', 'To'], as_index=False) # group the day by routes
        .apply(lambda route: route.shape[0] / date_group.shape[0]) # divide the total of trips of that route by the total trips of that day
    )
    return daily_avg

# Get route's relationship
routes_series = df.groupby('cardNumber').apply(get_routes) # retrive routes per passenger
routes_series = routes_series[routes_series!=0] # remove groups without the target type

# Create a named dataframe from the series output
routes_df = pd.DataFrame(routes_series.tolist(), columns=['Date', 'From', 'To'])

# Create dataframe, perform filter and calculations
daily_routes_df = (
    routes_df.query('From != To') # remove routes with same destination as the origin
    .groupby('Date').apply(get_daily_avg) # calculate the mean per date
    .rename(columns={None: 'Avg. Daily'}) # set name to previous output
    .drop(['From','To'], axis = 1) # drop out redundant info since there's such info at the index
    .reset_index() # remove MultiIndex to get a tidy dataframe
)

# Visualize results
print(daily_routes_df)
```

Output:

```
         Date From To  Avg. Daily
0  08/01/2020    2  1         1.0
```

Here, the average is 1 since there's only one count per group. Note that only the "transfer" type has been taking into account. The ones without it, or with no changing route, were further removed.

Comment: I ran this on my dataset but the Avg. Daily value is 1 for all 'from' and 'to' pairs. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Also, is there a way to account for the same `cardNumber` making two transfers in a day? In the example above, you'll notice that `cardNumber 999` makes a transfer in the morning and then a second one in the afternoon.

Comment: What is the relationship between "transfer" and "trip_pass"?

Comment: "trip_pass" is one of a number of types of transactions. "transfer" is a type of transaction that is registered when a passenger used "trip_pass", "stored_value" or a number of other transactions types first. When they board the second bus of their trip, the system recognizes that transaction as a 'transfer'. I have since created an attribute called `transfer` that is either a '0' for 'not a transfer' and '1' for 'transfer'.

Comment: Also, in the line of code `df_routes['n'] = 1`, I can change that value and that is what is returned in the dataframe.

Comment: Indeed, the way I was doing it, it would always return 1. I've edited the code, so please check if it makes sense to you and if it works.

Comment: About the transfers, I'm still confused. Could you show us the expected origin(s)/destination(s) output (without the daily average) for the passengers with cardNumber 999 and 888?

Comment: For cardNumber 999, there should be a transfer counted from route 1 to route 2 and a transfer counted from route 2 to route 1. This represents the two trips this passenger took in a day. For cardNumber 888, there should not be any transfers. For cardNumber 901, there is a transfer from route 20 to route 3. Ideally, I would like a table that shows the various combinations of routes and how many transfers occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, you would like to get the trip start and end out of your events and the first event corresponds with the starting point (the route name) and then calculate the number of tickets you have in your data set that have the same starting and endpoint.

If so, you can do this as follows

```
# srot the dataframe so you can use first/last
df_sorted= df.sort_values(['cardNumber', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True)

# calculate the counts do the counts, but only
# from the defined types
indexer_trip_points= df_sorted['type'].isin(['transfer'])
df_from_to= df_sorted[indexer_trip_points].groupby('cardNumber').agg(
                  start_date=('Date', 'first'),
                  trip_start=('routeName', 'first'), 
                  trip_end=('routeName', 'last'),
)
                      
df_from_to['start_date']= df_from_to['start_date'].dt.date
df_counts= df_from_to.groupby(['trip_start', 'trip_end', 'start_date']).agg(
    count=('trip_start', 'count')
)
df_counts.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df_counts.groupby(['trip_start', 'trip_end']).agg(
    avg=('count', 'mean')
)
```

This results in:

```
                     avg
trip_start trip_end     
2          1           1
3          3           1
```

As you can notice, the last entry has the same start- as endpoint. So probably you need to filter out trips, for which you don't have complete data yet. E.g. if in your case a route can never end with the same routeName as it started, you could simply filter them by comparing the two columns.